# Turn Based Multiplayer Skeleton Demo App

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to get the demo app for turn based multiplayer working and I'm having an issue.

I have the code compiling and running but I'm getting this error any time I'm trying to actually connect to or create a game.

DrawingActivity(13235): Did not have warning or string to deal with: 6003

That error code corresponds to this

public static final int STATUS_MULTIPLAYER_DISABLED = 6003;

Even though under my app I have it set correctly

[image: Google Play Game Services]

I did notice there isn't an option for turn based multiplayer in the development console which is more than likely what is causing this issue. Any help or confirmation that this is an issue would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of turn-based? I.e. are players allowed to see things as they happen (constant client connections), or is it a post and reply type affair as one user finishes their turn? I only ask, because the two are very different

Comment: They just released integrated turn based capabilities about a week ago and I'm trying to get the demo app they provided to work

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go out to the app console, under MULTIPLAYER SETTINGS, there is now a setting for Turn-based multiplayer, right above Real-time multiplayer. Try setting that to ON and see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: lol I was just about to post that it is available now. Seems crazy they pushed the new features before updating the developers console.