# SkeletonTBMP Gamehelper.getTurnBasedMatch() Doesnt exist

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Hi I'm trying to experiment with turn-based multiplayer so I imported the SkeletonTBMP sample into ecplise and referenced BaseGameUtils and google-play-services-lib libraries. The problem is

```
mHelper.getTurnBasedMatch()
```

errors out saying that getTurnBasedMatch() isnt defined for GameHelper. Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct version of GameHelper.

android-samples-master\BasicSamples\libraries\BaseGameUtils\src\main\java\com\google\example\games\basegameutils\GameHelper.java

```
/**
 * Returns the tbmp match received through an invitation notification. This
 * should be called from your GameHelperListener's
 * @link{GameHelperListener#onSignInSucceeded} method, to check if there's a
 * match available.
 * @return The match, or null if none was received.
 */
public TurnBasedMatch getTurnBasedMatch() {
    if (!checkState(TYPE_DEVELOPER_ERROR, "getTurnBasedMatch",
            "TurnBasedMatch is only available when connected "
                    + "(after getting the onSignInSucceeded callback).",
            STATE_CONNECTED)) {
        return null;
    }
    return mTurnBasedMatch;
}
```

Make sure it has that method in it. I think I had to update that file locally.

The issue I'm having now that I have that working I outlined here.

[Turn Based Multiplayer Skeleton Demo App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189516/turn-based-multiplayer-skeleton-demo-app)

If you get the code compiling let me know if you have this same issue. I have yet to get a response from anyone as to how to fix it.

Thanks!